# Enable editing mode for tableView when button is pressed

Tags: ios, uitableview

This has probably been asked before but I'm new to iOS Development and when I found confused me. I have a tableView and want to allow the user to tap a button that says "Edit" and they can delete items. I also want the edit button to become a "Done" button, which will stop edit mode. (The user can add data into the tableView from another option, which I will probably need to research how to do.) I don't have a storyboard as I built the app in an app called Interface. Everything is all in code.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the `UITableViewDelegate` methods.
I presume the 'Done'/'Edit' Button is the same in some place such as your `UINavigationBar`?
You will have to manually change the title for the button.

Remember to set your ViewController as the delegate for tableview too.

This delegate method informs that you wish to have the table eidtable.

```
– tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:
```

This method tells you you will start editing:

```
– tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:
```

(hint: change button title here)

Likewise this tells you editing is done:

```
– tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:
```

(hint: change button title here)

Answer (score 0):

The `UIViewController` class provides a method that gives you the standard Edit/Done button. You can do something like:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [self editButtonItem];
```

This standard button is setup to call the `setEditing:animated:` method. When used with a `UITableViewController`, the table view is automatically toggled between regular and edit mode along with the view controller.

There are plenty of specific table view delegate and data source methods you need to implement on top of this to facilitate actual table editing but using this standard button at least easily lets you toggle in and out of editing mode.